# About irreducible morphisms

Tags: representation-theory, quiver

A morphism $f: X\to Y$ in mod A is called irreducible if

1. f is not a section,
2. f is not a retraction,
3. and whenever $f = gh $ for some morphisms $h: X \to Z$ and $g: Z \to Y$, then either $h$ is a section or $g$ is a retraction.

Now I am reading Schiffler's book "Quiver Representation",

[image]
Proposition 7.4 (2)  states the fact that if $f: X\to Y$ is an irreducible morphsim, then $f$ admits no nontrivial factorization.

I have two questions:

- What is trivial factorization or nontrivial factorization of $f$?
- In the proof of Proposition 7.4 (2), $f$ is injective, then $f$ is not surjective, (Proposition 7.4 (1)) and thus $h$ cannot be a retraction. I don't know why $h$ is not a retraction.

Comment: Could you give more details about what the Proposition says? Regarding your first question: it's the third property in the definition of an irreducible morphism. In plain terms, the trivial factorizations are those of the form $X\to X\oplus Y\to Z$ or $X\to Z\oplus Y\to Z$.

Comment: @Hanno Thank you. I have added Proposition 7.4.

Comment: Now asked also on MathOverflow: [About irreducible morphisms](https://mathoverflow.net/q/267718).

Answer (score 0):

$f=hg$. If $f$ is both injective and surjective, then it is an isomorphism i.e there exists $f^{-1}:Y \to X$ such that $f.f^{-1}=1_Y$. Thus $1_Y=f.f^{-1}=hgf^{-1}$, so $gf^{-1}$ is the right inverse of $h$ i.e. $h$ is a retraction.

A retraction necessarily is surjective. $f$ is not surjective, it seems that this will imply $h$ is not surjective.